# Unable to upload data even after partitioning in VoltDB

Tags: sql, database, voltdb

We are trying to upload 80 GB of data in 2 host servers each with 48 GB RAM(in total 96GB). We have partitioned table too. But even after partitioning, we are able to upload data only upto 10 GB. In VMC interface, we checked the size worksheet. The no of rows in the table is 40,00,00,000 and table maximum size is 1053,200,000k and minimum size is 98,000,000K. So, what is issue in uploading 80GB even after partitioning and what is this table size?

Answer (score 1):

The size worksheet provides minimum and maximum size in memory that the number of rows would take, based on the schema of the table. If you have VARCHAR or VARBINARY columns, then the difference between min and max can be quite substantial, and your actual memory use is usually somewhere in between, but can be difficult to predict because it depends on the actual size of the strings that you load.

But I think the issue is that the minimum size is 98GB according to the worksheet, meaning if any nullable strings are null, or any not-null strings would be an empty string.  Even without taking into account the heap size and any overhead, this is higher than your 96GB capacity.

What is your kfactor setting? If it is 0, there will be only one copy of each record. If it is 1, there will be two copies of each record, so you would really need 196GB minimum in that configuration.

The size per record in RAM depends on the datatypes chosen and if there are any indexes. Also, VARCHAR values longer than 15 characters or 63 bytes are stored in pooled memory which carries more overhead than fixed-width storage, although it can reduce the wasted space if the values are smaller than the maximum size.

If you want some advice on how to minimize the per-record size in memory, please share the definition of your table and any indexes, and I might be able to suggest adjustments that could reduce the size.

You can add more nodes to the cluster, or use servers with more RAM to add capacity.

Disclaimer: I work for VoltDB.